# How to restructure my JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I implemented an aggregation function but the only problem I have now is that I lost my key: value format e.g `[{name:"Apples",val:8},{name:"Banana",val: 9}]`.

```
function agrregate(a){
    var targetObj = {};
    var result;

    var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
    var trees= b.length;

    if(!trees){
        trees = 0
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < trees; i++) {
        if (!targetObj.hasOwnProperty(b[i].key)) {
            targetObj[b[i].key] = 0;
        }
        targetObj[b[i].key] += b[i].val;
    }
    result = JSON.stringify(targetObj);
    return result;
}
```

This is the result i get when agrregate function completes.

```
{"Apple":8,"Banana":9}
```

Instead of

```
{name:"Apple", val:8}, {name:"Banana", val:9}
```

Comment: JSON (or JS) can't do that - you cannot have an object, with two same property names having different values - `{name: 'a', name: 'b'}` will be evaluated to `{name: 'b'}`

Comment: What does your source data look like?

Answer (score 1):

Use a reducer to aggregate. You don't need to do stuff with `JSON` stringify/parse.

To get back to an array of objects, you use `map` and `Object.keys`

```js
var test = [{name:"Apples",val:5},{name:"Banana",val: 9},{name:"Apples",val:3}]

var aggregate = function(arr) { 
  return arr.reduce(function(result, obj) { // Create one object (result) 
    result[obj.name] = (result[obj.name] || 0) + obj.val; // Add a new key/or increase
    return result // Return the object
  }, {});
};

var wrap = function(obj) {
   return Object.keys(obj) // Create an array of keys
     .map(function(key) {
       return { // Specify the format
         name: key, 
         val: obj[key]
       };
     });
};

console.log(aggregate(test));
console.log(wrap(aggregate(test)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative but what i need now is to be able to do  a key value pair loop.

Comment: @MadulaShokengSelowa you *can*. This works just fine, yields your desired output.

Comment: `aggregate` gets you from array to object, `wrap` gets you from object to array. I'm not sure what else you need, can you elaborate?

Comment: It will only print the value how would i also print the key. im using AngularJs if im being stubborn harded not to get the point even an example can do. thanks.

Comment: My apologize for being a dummy im still having a bit of punches there and there regarding data structures but it works now.

Comment: It's okay. It's still hard for me to explain things like `reduce` and `map`... If you ask specific questions about parts of the code and explain what you eventually need to do, it's easier to help you out!